# Problems when printing in C#

Tags: c#

```
    private void PrintHelpPage()
    {
        // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting1 = new WebBrowser();

        // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
            new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);
        webBrowserForPrinting1.DocumentCompleted +=
            new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

        // Set the Url property to load the document.
        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"F:\fichinha.html");
        webBrowserForPrinting1.Url = new Uri(@"F:\fichinha2.html");
    }

    private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

        // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have this code for printing an HTML file, what happens is:

Some of the letters do not appear! Including special characters and non-special...

Example: 1 of the pages: "Agora pode consultar" , appears "Agora pode cons  tar"

Answer (score 1):

have you set the encoding, e.g. UTF-8?

```
webBrowserForPrinting.Document.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
```

and the same for webBrowserForPrinting1

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: The object reference was not defined as an object instance